# Matplotlib figure making multiple plots Horizonaly

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using plt.figure() , can we get Multiple plots horizontally. Below gives vertical, and tried using
plt.figure(nrows=1, ncols=2), and No such Syntax was legal.

```
fig = plt.figure() #nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x=res['actual'],y=res[0])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x=res['actual'],y=res[0])
res['diff']=res['actual']-res[0]
#plt.hist(res['diff'])

res['diff']=res['actual']-res[0]
plt.hist(res['diff'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(res['diff'], showmeans=True)

`fig = plt.figure() #nrows=1, ncols=2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x=res['actual'],y=res[0])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(x=res['actual'],y=res[0])
res['diff']=res['actual']-res[0]
#plt.hist(res['diff'])

res['diff']=res['actual']-res[0]
plt.hist(res['diff'])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(res['diff'], showmeans=True)
```

Comment: I think the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) are pretty clear on this

Comment: Friendo i can help you, what you should try is to create multiple plot in a loop

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_subplot(row, col, index)` are incorrect.

As your provided code is not replicable such as it contains `res['...']`. I'll give an intuitive and generalized example for you to follow along.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)
y = np.exp(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131) # specify as ax1
ax1.plot(x, y, c='red')
fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(x, y) # without specify ax
fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
plt.plot(x, y, ':')

plt.show()
```

For quick plot, I prefer this due to readability.

```
plt.subplots(1,3)
plt.subplot(131); plt.plot(x, y, c='red')
plt.subplot(132); plt.plot(x, y)
plt.subplot(133); plt.plot(x, y, ':')
plt.show()
```

Both are giving the same [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jszLc.png).